# A function that passes a function and a integer. Warning: passing argument of "" from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c++, c, function, debugging

So, this is the code:

```
void pass(void(), int);
void hello(int);

int main(void)
{
pass(hello,0);

return 0;
}

void pass(void rfunc(),int a)
{
rfunc(a);
}

void hello(int a)
 {
printf("%d",a);
}
```

The output of '0' is printed as expected. However, I'm getting these warnings which I'm trying to fix. The error says:

```
in function 'main':
warning: passing argument 1 of 'pass' from incompatible pointer  type
```

How do I fix this warning?

Comment: C or C++? Those are different languages with different answers.

Comment: The details of what causes the incompatibility are different between C and C++; the fix, curiously, is the same.  It would still be a very good idea not to dual-tag the question — it annoys people (me included).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter to `pass` expects a function pointer of type `void (*)()`, but you're passing in a function pointer of type `void (*)(int)`.  That's an incompatible type.

Change the parameter of `pass` to accepts the proper type:

```
void pass(void(int), int);
...
void pass(void rfunc(int),int a) 
{
    ...
```